# Compactness and continuity problems

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function from compact set $K$ (so $f$ is uniformly continuous). Then show for $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists A >0$ (depending on $\epsilon)$ such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq A|x-y| + \epsilon,$$ for $x,y \in K$(Hint: argue by contradiction)

Okay so I have some ideas, but I didn't feel like they were going anywhere.

To prove statement, assume that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\nexists A >0$ such that the inequality holds or $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\forall A >0$ is inequality is false. Then arrive at some contradiction.

So I decided to take $A = \epsilon$. But that wasn't going anywhere. Can I just get a hint? No answer please. Note that I think it is better to consider the case $|f(x)| \leq A|x| + \epsilon$ by setting $f(0) = 0$ as I think the general case in here can be replaced by a translation.

Comment: What is $K$? A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ because you write $\lvert x - y \rvert$ for $x, y \in K$?

Comment: @PaulFrost, it is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for contradiction, that there exists $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n, y_n \in K$ satisfying
$$
\tag{1} |f(x_n) - f(y_n) | \geq n |x_n - y_n| + \varepsilon_0.
$$
Using the compactness of $K$ we extract a converging subsequence from $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$. Namely, let $n_k$ be a subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n_k} \to x_0$ and $y_{n_k} \to y_0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $K$ and $K$ is compact, it follows that $f$ is bounded. Fix $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x\in K$.  From $(1)$ we get
$$
2M \geq n_k |x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| + \varepsilon_0.
$$
Since $n_k |x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}|$ is bounded above, and $n_k \to \infty$, it follows that $|x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| \to 0$. But then, the continuity of $f$ implies $f(x_{n_k}) - f(y_{n_k}) \to 0$ and passing to the limit in $(1)$ along $\{n_k\}$ we get
$$
0 \geq \limsup\limits_{k\to \infty} n_k |x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| + \varepsilon_0 \geq \varepsilon_0 > 0
$$ 
which is a contradiction.

Comment: What if $n|x_n-y_n|\to 0$?

Comment: So I wrote the statement wrong then

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis, then we get (assuming WLOG that $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge) that $x_n$ and $y_n$ both converge to the same limit, hence $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \to 0$ by continuity of $f$, but that was supposed to be bounded below by $\varepsilon_0 > 0$.

Comment: So basically $n_{k}|x_{n_k}| \to \infty$ as $n_k \to \infty$. So $\epsilon >0 $doesn't even matter.

Comment: @Hawk, no $\varepsilon > 0 $ does matter, and we don't have $n_k |x_{n_k}| \to \infty$.  I'll write up a complete argument now.

Comment: How does $|x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| \to 0$ again?

Comment: @Hawk, since $n_k |x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| \leq 2M$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that $|x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}|  \leq \frac{2M}{n_k} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

The rough Lipschitz condition does not give lot of control when $x$ and $y$ are close. May start by noticing that for $|x-y|>\delta$, there exists a bounded function $\omega:[\delta,diam(K)]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\omega(|x-y|)$.